# Can Qt 64 bit generate 32 bit executable?

Tags: qt, executable

I have 64 bit Qt installed. Qt creater is 32 bit and i am making executable with MINGW 32 bit. I am using windeploqt to copy all the dlls in the exe folder. Can you please tell the DLL's related to Qt are 64 bit or 32 bit?

Answer (score 0):

To generate a 32 bit executable you need a **32 bit kit** in Qt Creator. A kit consists of a set of values that define one environment(tool chain, Qt version, debugger, etc).

To configure your kits go to: Tools > Options > Build & Run > Kits.

If you don't have a 32 bit kit, you should create one. More info on how to to that [here](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-targets.html).

Once you have a configured 32 bit kit, [activate](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-configuring-projects.html) that kit for your project and you should be able to build your project and generate the 32 bit executable.

ps: You need Qt 32 bit (and i'm not talking about qt creator).